# How would you write the name Anibal in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, katakana, names

So my name is written Anibal, I'm from Brazil, just so you know.
I'd like to know how would you write it in japanese, I'm in doubt between A-ni-ba-ru and A-ni-ba-e-ru. Any further explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: Audio of someone pronouncing your name would be helpful for people who don't know how Portuguese(?) vowels sound. (Alternatively, a phonemic transcription, if you know how to do that.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answers! That was bugging me for weeks. I'm using this website for the first time and I really hope I'm using it correctly. Will look forward to using it more often.
Again, thanks a lot for the explanations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this kind of question, you can start by seeing how other people spell it.  I searched the Japanese Wikipedia for **Anibal**.  Here were the top two results:

- [Anibal Alejandro Sanchez](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%A2%E3%83%8B%E3%83%90%E3%83%AB%E3%83%BB%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%82%A7%E3%82%B9) - **アニバル**・アレハンドロ・サンチェス
- [Tarso Anibal Santanna Marques](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%BF%E3%83%AB%E3%82%BD%E3%83%BB%E3%83%9E%E3%83%AB%E3%82%B1%E3%82%B9) - タルソ・**アニバル**・サンタナ・マルケス

How you transcribe a name usually depends on its *pronunciation*, not its *spelling*, so it's possible that an Anibal from a different region would have a different transcription.  But you said you're from Brazil, and so is the second person I linked to above, so it seems reasonable to spell your name the same way as his.  And that's true regardless of whether it's based on spelling or pronunciation--following convention in transcribing names is usually a good thing.  So based on this, I think **アニバル** seems like a good spelling.

If you can't read katakana, that's **A-ni-ba-ru**, just like your first guess.  That would usually be written without hyphens, so it's **Anibaru**.

Comment: I think アニバル is the generic Japanese transcription based on ローマ字 alone, not based on pronunciation.

Comment: @Earthling Oh, I see.  Well, I'll leave my answer up, because I think following convention is probably a good thing.  It seems that アニバル is a lot more common than アニバウ.  But maybe I should rephrase my answer to emphasize that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the final L is pronounced [u], so that Anibal could also be アニバウ (A-ni-ba-u), which represents the pronunciation more faithfully than アニバル (which sounds more like Anibaru, when pronounced as a Portuguese speaker would).